# Color formatting conditionally in a tableau list

Tags: tableau-api, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to conditionally format the progress till date to red for the date in the end date which has already passed or which is lesser than the current date and when the concern filter is yes.

Below is the screen shot:

[image]

Please help me how do I Make the progress column red for end dates which have passed or lesser than the current date and when the concern filter is yes

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to color a column based another value (conditional formatting).

[image]

1. Data set looks like following:

[image]

2. Create a calculated field which will hold the color condition (I assume your data is in date format and not string):

   IF [Concern] = "Yes" AND [End Date] < TODAY() THEN "RED" ELSE "" END
3. Create a dummy calculated field:

[image]

4. We create a second dummy:

[image]

5. We add the dummy columns to the "columns" at the top

[image]

6. Make them to "Dual Axis"

[image]

7. Then click on "Marks" and "All". Drag color and drag it down to Color (1 in picture) and choose text (2 in picture)

[image]

8. Then drag the Progress column to the text field

[image]

9. Time to adjust layout. Right click and choose "Edit Axis"

[image]

9.1 Remove "Title" from "Axis Titles"

[image]

9.2 Remove the ticker marks

[image]

10. Choose the upper header and change the title

[image]

and remove the tickers

[image]

11. Then adjust the header space by dragging the line

[image]